# ExtJS 4.1 stop grid.Panel from closing

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have I view that extends `Ext.grid.Panel` and I want to be able to ask the user if he really wants to close the panel after he clicks [X]. I tried with

```
listeners: {
            beforedestroy: function() {
                               //console.log('In');
                return false;
            }
        },
```

but obviously it's not that simple. Any ideas on how to prevent the closing of the panel?

Thanks

Leron

P.S.

This is what I get from sencha forums, haven't test it yet:

```
Ext.create( 'Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'test',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    listeners: {
        beforeclose: function( window ) {
            Ext.Msg.confirm( 'Hey', 'Are you sure you want to close?', function( answer ) {
                if( answer == "yes" ) {
                    window.destroy();
                }
            } );
            return false;
        }
    }
} ).show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`beforeclose` event should work. No?

Update:

If you want to have some user interaction (i.e. confirmation question or saving data or something like that) it will be a bit tricky...

First, in the constructor of the view do something like this:

```
this.on('beforeclose', function() { 
   return this.myCloseHandler(function() { this.close(); }, this);
});
this.alreadyAsked = false;
```

Than create handler:

```
myCloseHandler: function(callback, scope) {
    if (this.alreadyAsked === false) {
        this.alreadyAsked = true;
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            msg: 'Are you sure?',
            fn: function(btn) {
               if (btn == 'yes')
                  Ext.callback(callback, scope);
               else 
                  this.alreadyAsked = false;   
            }
        });
        return false;

    }
    return true;   
}
```

Idea is - you return false immediately but have some flag and condition to go through the same logic without confirmation.

Comment: `Fires before the user closes the panel. Return false from any listener to stop the close event being fired` this is the part that I don't understand. It seems that just adding listener wont work, I need to `return false` from a listener or event to stop further execution but this is the theory I have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: This is from the sencha docs about the listeners, what I understand is that I have to fire an event inside the listener and to return false from this event, but it sounds a little confusing to me. I haven't got much time today to experiment but it seems like a standart task so I try to find a real life solution because the info that I found just confuses me most. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Exactly. You return false if you want stop closing the panel. What exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: You mean that you need to have some user interaction and then possibly to close panel?

Comment: Hmm, now I'm even more confused :) Anyways, I tried sverel listeners including `beforeclose` but my example above as it is, dosn't stop the closing even tough i return false. But in fact what I need is maybe what you mean by `user interaction` I want to hook the action when [x] is pressed and show a confirmation box asking the user if he is sure that he wants to close the panel, and close it only if the press "OK" otherwise I want to stop further execution and leave the panel open.

Comment: Yes. I had to do something similar... It's gonna be complicated. Let me try to write something inside the answer

Comment: Lol, thanks, if you want look through the snippet I get from a snecha forum user. I don't have the project on my home PC so I'll have to wait till tommorow to try your idea, but am really grateful for your attention. Perfect as always, gonna comment tommorow on what is the outcome. +1 from me!

Comment: Well... that snippet somewhat brut force :) I'd prefer my approach

Answer (score 2):

The technique I use is simply to do a window hide rather than the default destroy of the window and add a beforehide event listener. This prevents that all the components in your window that you want to prevent to destroy, are destroyed anyway. The hide event is a quite innocent event to this with. Then the Ext.msg comes, maybe even only on a certain condition. And your response on the break message finished the job. Otherwise no harm done, because false is returned.

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
       .... your window specs ...
       closeAction : 'hide',
       buttons : [{
            text    : 'Close',
            scope   : me,
            handler : function() {
                win.hide(); // not destroy !!! that comes later !!!
            }
        }],
        listeners : {
            scope  : me,
            'beforehide' : function(window) {
                if (some_condition == true) {
                    Ext.Msg.confirm( 'Confirm close of window', 'You really wanna close this window ?', function( answer ) {
                        if( answer == "yes" ) {
                            window.destroy();
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }

            },
            'destroy' : function(window) {
                  // do something after the window destruction //
                  alert('Another window smashed');
            }
        }
        ... rest of your window specs
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is no need in heavy constructions. The following works perfect for me:

```
beforeclose: function(window) {
    Ext.Msg.confirm("Hey", "Are you sure you want to close?", function(answer) {
        if (answer == "yes") {
            window.events.beforeclose.clearListeners();
            window.close();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```